# Total socket count steadily increasing, tcp/udp sockets steady. Why?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tcp, unix-sockets

I have a server (Ubuntu 16.04.5) running sockets.io and a few other things.

This server is running about 5 or 6 different python apps and sockets.io. When the server reaches this level of ~6144 sockets it stops accepting new ones. As you can see, there aren't really that many active connections so what is going on here? It's got me stumped.

TCP connections are as follows:

```
root@01:~# netstat -an| awk '/tcp/ {print $6}'|sort|uniq -c
 44 CLOSE_WAIT
 518 ESTABLISHED
 71 FIN_WAIT1
 15 FIN_WAIT2
 5 LAST_ACK
 10 LISTEN
 26 SYN_RECV
```

However the total socket allocated count is much higher and steadily increasing...why?

```
root@01:~# ss -s
Total: 6128 (kernel 6144)
TCP:   6028 (estab 523, closed 5381, orphaned 7, synrecv 0, timewait 0/0), ports 0

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         6144      -         -        
RAW       0         0         0        
UDP       4         3         1        
TCP       647       644       3        
INET      651       647       4        
FRAG      0         0         0
```

Thanks